# Should default language be english?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, language-translation

Setting the default language to English in `admin/config/regional/language` has been told by many developers as recommended. 
But you can set it to another language as well? If you set in another language all your string translations will you use the other language as default for translations. But how about modules and the default language (source language) for translation that is default always using English as source language.

There is something really confusing here.

You can have English as default language ( set in your global configuration) but at the same time set for example Dutch as default (preferred language in your Content type (language settings) in `admin/structure/types/manage/page?destination=/admin/structure/types`
If you set Dutch as default language it will be the source language for your content translation.

Answer (score 0):

English not default language was really a problem in Drupal 7, but Drupal 8 has greatly imporoved on that matter and so far only small glitches have been reported and might not be any at this time.

I have build Drupal 8 sites with non-english as default language without any problems.

I would suggest making this decision and change as early as possible in setting up the website and test that id does not have any side effects.

A content type default language different than the Site default is a flexibility offered by Drupal.  And the two are used in different parts of the site. What part is consufing ?

For example the screenshot below shows a setup for the following scenario: A native GREEK responsible for WRITING content of this particular content type. The content would be written first in GREEK (3) and than allowed to be translated (1) in available languages.  But we also allow an editor to choose another language as the source language (2).

[image]

Each one of those language settings is independent.

Comment: Translations of strings in your twig templates will use the Site default always. There I like to use english always.